# Localization to Arabic iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, localization

I have designed my UI in english, when I have added localization the UI elements position got changed.
[image]
How to keep UI elements in their position after adding localization?

More Details:
I am loading localization from

> edit scheme->run-> options->application languge ->application region
>   to Saudi Arab

Comment: Arabic is a right-to-left language. Why would you not want the UI elements to reflect this?

Comment: because elements should be in same position see the white button shifted it's postion from left to right,it should remain in left after localized to arabic.

Comment: This is a feature, not a bug…

Comment: what will be the solution now to keep left elements in left side only? i don't want elements position change,i need help button should be left and i canhelp will right always irrespective of localization.Can you please sugestion a solution for this

Comment: Here is answer for my Question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14724767/ios-disable-ui-mirroring-in-xib

Comment: Change the Auto Layout constraint types from Leading/Trailing to use Left/Right instead.

Answer (score 2):

Changing the semantic content attribute for the two views or the container view will fix it. 
This is a highly recommended read 
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/SupportingRight-To-LeftLanguages/SupportingRight-To-LeftLanguages.html